# Sbt: when to use testQuick and how does it determine which tests to skip?

Tags: scala, sbt

According to sbt documentation, when running `testQuick`, it executes

- The tests that failed in the previous run
- The tests that were not run before
- The tests that have one or more transitive dependencies, maybe in a different project, recompiled.

How does sbt determine which tests qualify? If it is based on cached results, where is this cache?

Comment: I would remove the Scala.js tag here. This is not specific to Scala.js at all.

Comment: @gzm0 I suppose sbt wouldn't behave much differently when compiling to js rather than java. Done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default its kept in `target/streams/test/test/$global/streams/succeded_tests` (path may vary depending on build settings) if You are interested how exactly its picking tests to run check `testQuickFilter` method in: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/fd20d3039ad06cbee47c6386dc5839060417014b/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Defaults.scala#L758